# Is there an atomic "set if empty" operation in anyof the Map Sub classes?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have to implement logic where I need to atomically set an object for a key only if the key is currently not mapped to any value. I can implement this myself but don't want to reinvent the wheel if it's already been done somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ConcurrentHashMap.putifAbsent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29)

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value, associate
>   it with the given value. This is equivalent to

```
if (!map.containsKey(key))
   return map.put(key, value);    
else
   return map.get(key);
```

> except that the action is performed atomically.

Answer (score 5):

`ConcurrentHashMap` has `putIfAbsent` method, may be it's what you need. And as dogbane pointed out, thit is actually defined in base interface `ConcurrentMap`, so `ConcurrentSkipListMap` has it too.

Comment: Whoa.  You two tied down to the second.

Comment: using the same memory barrier maybe?

Comment: Yes, it has to be, obviously :)